# how to slide view on finger position

Tags: android, android-listview, touch-event, ontouchlistener

i have a custom listview that i need to be able to slide up and down while the user has his/her finger still on the screen. How can this be done? I provided the ontouchEvent thats in the custom listview class. I tried this.setY(event.getY()) but it does reallt work. How can i do this?

```
    @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //System.out.println("First ["+this.getFirstVisiblePosition()+"]");

    float y = event.getY();


    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            this.setY(event.getY());

            if ( ( y - startY) > THRESHOLD && STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED && !STATE_REFRESHING && Ref_once ) {
                if(mListener!=null) mListener.onRefresh();
                Log.d("CUSTOM LIST"," FOODHOTER LIST LISTENER WORKING");
                this.setClickable(false);
                Ref_once=false;
            }
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            startY = y;
           // STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED = getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0; // We are on the first element so we can enable refresh
                      STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED =listIsAtTop()  ;

            this.setClickable(true);
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            STATE_REFRESHING = false;
            this.setClickable(true);
            Ref_once=true;
        }

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to `setScrollY()` of your listview to match the current `y` captured by your `onTouch` listener.

```
 @Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    //System.out.println("First ["+this.getFirstVisiblePosition()+"]");

    final float y = event.getY();
    final float scrollY = listview.getScrollY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE: {

            listview.setScrollY(Y + scrollY);

            if ( ( y - startY) > THRESHOLD && STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED && !STATE_REFRESHING && Ref_once ) {
                if(mListener!=null) mListener.onRefresh();
                Log.d("CUSTOM LIST"," FOODHOTER LIST LISTENER WORKING");
                this.setClickable(false);
                Ref_once=false;
            }
        }
        break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: {
            startY = y;
           // STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED = getFirstVisiblePosition() == 0; // We are on the first element so we can enable refresh
                      STATE_REFRESH_ENABLED =listIsAtTop()  ;

            this.setClickable(true);
        }
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: {
            STATE_REFRESHING = false;
            this.setClickable(true);
            Ref_once=true;
        }

    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: nope, it doesn't work. I need to be able to drag the entire listview down when i drag my finger down and back up when i move my finger up

Comment: Made some changes. Now referencing the listview, not sure what it's variable name is from your code and changed to delta scroll based on ACTION_MOVE.